# Glade / GTK - Change Title Bar icon size

Tags: gtk, glade

I would like to know if there is a way to change the size of the title bar icon and the title bar itself using Glade or GTK.

The way I see it, Glade does not provide us with any options to change the Title bar size or title bar icon size, it only provides an option for specifying the Title bar icon image.

In essence I want to create a Title Bar that looks like the one in the image below.

[Title Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut0FS.png)

Comment: You mean window title? I suspect that out of Gtk's hand, windows managers only allow setting window title and icon itself

Comment: You can try shoving your image in a GtkHeaderBar; no guarantee that it will resize to fit the image, though...

Comment: Yes, the window title. Guess I will have to use a GtkHeaderBar and push that to the TitleBar